# table creation logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to take two tables I have a perform a data transformation to create a single table. I have an `events table` and `user table`:

```
Events: {id, user_id, start_date, end_date, cost...}

Users: {id, name, ...}
```

I am trying to create a table at that shows user spend at a daily level, assuming the user start with a starting cost of zero and it goes up after every event.

The intended **output** would be:

```
{date, userid, beginning_balance, sum(cost), num_of_events}
```

i need some direction on how to tackle this one as I am not very familiar with data transformation within SQL

Comment: Would you like to add sample data to the question as text.

Comment: If the start date and end date are different would you like the cost allocated to the start or end date?

Comment: updated, that should have been date not 'data' in the output.

Comment: good question @P.Salmon i am going to assume start date and end dates are the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT
    data,
    User.id AS userid,
    0 AS beginning_balance,
    SUM(cost) AS cost,
    COUNT(0) AS num_of_events
FROM
    Users
    LEFT JOIN Events ON (user_id = Users.id)
GROUP BY
    Users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit unclear but you may be after something like this

```
drop table if exists event;
create table event(id int auto_increment primary key, user_id int,start_date date, end_date date, cost int);
insert into event (user_id,start_date , end_date, cost) values
(1,'2017-01-01','2017-01-01',10),(1,'2017-01-01','2017-01-01',10),
(1,'2017-02-01','2017-01-01',10),
(2,'2017-01-01','2017-01-01',10);

select e.user_id,start_date, 
            ifnull(
            (select  sum(cost)
            from event e1
            where e1.user_id = e.user_id and e1.start_date <e.start_date
            ),  0 )beginning_balance,
            sum(cost),count(*) 
           as num_of_events
from users u
join event e on e.user_id = u.userid
group by e.user_id,start_date

+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
| user_id | start_date | beginning_balance | sum(cost) | num_of_events |
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
|       1 | 2017-01-01 |                 0 |        20 |             2 |
|       1 | 2017-02-01 |                20 |        10 |             1 |
|       2 | 2017-01-01 |                 0 |        10 |             1 |
+---------+------------+-------------------+-----------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```